# Class 'Video' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am having trouble with a Laravel 4 application of mine. I created a Video class, model and schema. When I am in the "admin" section of my app, the Video class works and I can create, read, edit and delete videos without any issue. When I try to access the Videos section of page at the front end, I get the Class 'Video' not found. It shows this section of my routes file as the problem.

```
Route::get('video', array('as' => 'video.list', function() {
    Video::tester(); // Will result in our die() message
    return View::make('site.pages.videos')->with('entries', Video::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get());
}));
```

I added a die message to see if the app was even getting into my Video Model, but no such luck.

Here is my model:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

class Video extends \Eloquent 
{
    public static function tester()
    {
        die("Just a test.");
    }

    protected $table = 'videos';

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need anything else from me, just say so.

Comment: did you add this piece of code? `use App\Models\Video`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::get('video', array('as' => 'video.list', function() {
    App\Models\Video::tester(); // Will result in our die() message
    return View::make('site.pages.videos')->with('entries', Video::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get());
}));
```

also you can study namespace so that you can get a clear understanding where you were going wrong.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I really don't know why it's not working here, but it is working on all my other models, which are done the same way.

Comment: Because of the namespace you provided ie. App\Models. so whenever you call this class you have to use App\Models\ClassName...Otherwise it wont work.i suggest you read a little bit about namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You've namespaced your model under `App\Models`, but trying to access `Video` from the root namespace. Try `App\Models\Video::tester()`